# After I execute proxychains my the login screen keep looping in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, login-screen

I was messing around with proxychain and now I can't log in to Kali Linux after restarting. It was working fine until I logged out, but FSR when I tried to log in the login screen is looping. It happened to me three or four times now.

At first, I thought it was because I'm messing up the configuration and it seems fine after I completely reinstall the OS. I tried all the methods in [Ubuntu 16.04 stuck on login loop][1], but none of them worked.

Update:

I keep restarting Kali after each line and found that the login loop occurs only after I execute the proxychain command which is
`proxychains4 firefox`.I have recorded all the process for reference but it's splitted to two videos

part 1 : https://youtu.be/y-W0UUhLEwg

part 2 : https://youtu.be/8HZE6rPx3nU

also it's about 10 min long in total

Comment: The messages have nothing to do with the problem. And you're running a VM so you should have backups/snapshots therefore you can start over from there. If you don't then make sure to have them next time.

Comment: Everytime i try to run proxychains the login screen loop appears after logging out but everything runs fine until then

Comment: So your problem has nothing to do with Kali really.  It should be titled  `an edit I am making to proxychains.conf is preventing me from logging back in` .. perhaps you should post the proxychains.conf file you edited?  I know squat about this but 100% about how to troubleshoot things.

Comment: i really didn't edit much in proxychains. i only remove the # from dynamic and add a # to static and the existing IP then added a couple of IPs that I get from online. I uploaded a video in the edited post, also thank you for the title advice. I'm new here so ... yah

Answer (score 1):

You have damaged something, and you know that Kali is very short on friendliness or repair tools.

Recover from your backup.  All Kali VM users keep backups.

If no backup, spin up a new machine. Make sure you have V2023.1 and that it is up to date.

If you need data from the old machine, get it via (1) a USB Drive (USB Pass Through) or (2) Set up Samba and map a folder.

**Follow up:**

You said reinstalling Kali and then installing Proxychains caused the log in issue again.

Check this article for fully installing Proxychains.

[Proxchains install](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-setup-proxychains-in-linux-without-any-errors/)

How to setup Proxychains?
To setup proxychains you will first need the tor service, most of the time the service is preinstalled. To check if there is tor service available or not just use this command.

service tor status

If you get any error after using this command then it means tor service is not available in your system, to install tor service use the following command.

We had already installed tor service before so there will be a difference in execution. If you get any error while doing this then check below steps in this article.
After installing tor service, now we need to configure proxychains. To do so use the following command.

nano /etc/proxychains.conf
You can use any editor of your choice here we are using nano, you can also use vim, leafpad or sublime etc.

In the configuration, you will see “#” which means bash language comments. You can use arrow keys to scroll down and do the following changes.

Remove Dynamic chain from comment
comment Strict chain and Random chain
Remove proxy DNS from comment
write socks5 127.0.0.1 9050 in last line of proxy list
Save the configuration file and exit the terminal. The proxychains setup is complete. To start proxychains first restart the tor service and then launch proxychains in firefox with a link for a particular search engine like bing, duckduck go. Use the following commands:

service tor restart

Comment: So I reinstalled kali linux again from scratch and run proxychains and it's the same login loop again.

Comment: It looks like proxy chains is responsible.  Either not compatible with Kali or an different version required

Comment: Make sure the TOR service is properly installed.  I added this to my answer

Comment: I was doing it the same as in the link.

Comment: it seems only when I run the specific line and there is an update in the post. thankyou for your suggestion

Comment: Make sure you are using the current version of Kali and Kernel is V 6+ . Kali is supposed to work as per the link I posted

Answer (score 0):

I was busy with my studies and I couldn't post it. So I found the cause of the problem. It's because each time i use the cli i used to switch to admin with the command "sudo su" and i couldn't run firefox on it, so I copied firefox and run it in admin and FSR it breaks the sys files or something. And for the solution we can just run it with user account. I admit it and I know I was a dumb, well "Learn from mistakes" I think.